# How to count the number of commas in a string?

Tags: teradata

I use teradata. No access to functions, UDFs, stored procedures

Table

```
id  attribute
1   strength, power
2   ring, wig, puff
3   strength, ring
4   puff, wig
5   power
```

I need to count the number of attributes

```
id  att_number
1   2
2   3
3   2
4   2
5   1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which teradata version are you using? 14.0 or 13.0 or older

Comment: it is 13. i do not have otranslate, replace etc

Comment: Would your data have a definitive upper bound on the no. of commas present?

Comment: there are commas between attributes. The maximum number of attributes is 12 (for each id )

Comment: Do you have the ability to create a UDF in your environment? There aren't really any easy ways to do this with the default functions within TD 13. You could try a recursive CTE by that would get expensive if you are running this against a large table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course your site should install at least the oTranslate and oReplace UDFs. Then it's a simple

```
CHAR_LENGTH(col) - CHAR_LENGTH(OTRANSLATE(col, ',',''))
```

Without those functions it's a pain in the `<insert your favourite body part here>`. Simply try to implement a REPLACE without oREPLACE, complex SQL with a horrible performance.

In your case it's a bit easier. If the maximum number is 12 the most efficient way will be a straight:

```
CASE
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%' THEN 12
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'   THEN 11
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'     THEN 10
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'       THEN  9
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'         THEN  8
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%,%'           THEN  7
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%,%'             THEN  6
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%,%'               THEN  5
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%,%'                 THEN  4
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%,%'                   THEN  3
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%,%'                     THEN  2
   WHEN col LIKE '%,%'                       THEN  1
   ELSE                                            0
END
```

No need for nested CASE/POSITION/SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 3):

Using only `index` and `substring` functions, you would need a nested case statement which checks for a max of 12 attributes as show below. You would need to further nest the case statement to able to count upto 12 attributes, currently it can only count to a max of 2 attributes. [note: mytext=attributes]

```
SELECT id, mytext
,case 
when index(mytext, ',')= 0 then 0
when index(mytext, ',')>0 then  
                                    case
                                    when index(substring(mytext,  index(mytext, ','), length(mytext)), ',')=0 then 1
                                    when index(substring(mytext,  index(mytext, ','), length(mytext)), ',')>0 then 2
                                    end
end
from mydb.sd_test
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT colname
,CHARACTERS(TRIM(colname)) -CHARACTERS(TRIM(OREPLACE(colname,',',''))) +1
 SAMPLE 100  FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use a much simpler and efficient one liner code as below:

```
select length(trim(regexp_replace(Column_Name,'[^,]+','')));
```